# Redirecting to another lightning app from a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

Is it possible to open another lightning app from a component by using some lightning events like navigateToURL or any other option?

I am displaying a component showing all the AppMenueItems and want to rediect to specific lightning app on click of the specific links.

Thanks.